# How to Fix Install Clang and libgtk-3-dev in Flutter Doctor Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: flutter, flutter-doctor

I tried to install flutter requirement on ubuntu 22.04.LTS.

```
➜  ~ flutter doctor
```

In flutter doctor I found issue 1 category in linux toolchain

[image: Flutter-Doctor]

but after I tried in various ways still can't install `clang`

[image: Issue-2]

I've also tried to install `libgtk-3-dev` but so far it doesn't work

[image: Issue-3]

How to fix all broken packages, please tell me!

Answer (score 0):

From [flutter docs](https://docs.flutter.dev/get-started/install/linux) to install the linux requirements on a debian based.

```
sudo apt-get install clang cmake ninja-build pkg-config libgtk-3-dev liblzma-dev
```

Comment: I still have the same issue in packages have unmet dependencies clang-10, libgtk-3-dev, liblzma-dev, libstdc++-9-dev

Comment: try running `sudo apt update`  and the the install.

Comment: Okay thanks, I try ro reinstall ubuntu 22, work for me